# How to use the text between HTML tags to access an element - Selenium WebDriver

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have following HTML code.

```
<span class="ng-binding" ng-bind="::result.display">All Sector ETFs</span>

<span class="ng-binding" ng-bind="::result.display">China Macro Assets</span>

<span class="ng-binding" ng-bind="::result.display">Consumer Discretionary (XLY)</span>

<span class="ng-binding" ng-bind="::result.display">Consumer Staples (XLP)</span>
```

As it can be seen that tags are all the same for every line except the text between the tags.
How can I access each of the above line separately based on the text between tags.

Comment: can u post the parent html source code in which this span tags lie

Answer (score 2):

use the below as xpath

```
//span[text()='All Sector ETFs']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use x-path function text() for that.
For example

```
//span[text()="All Sector ETFs"]
```

to find first span

Answer (score 2):

You can use following xPath to find desired element based on text

```
String text = 'Your text';
//text may be ==>All Sector ETFs, China Macro Assets, Consumer Discretionary (XLY), Consumer Staples (XLP)
String xPath = "//*[contains(text(),'"+text+"')]";
```

By this you can find each elements..

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: Actually the text may be everything. You are using contains so just as long as it matches part of an element text it will find something.

Answer (score 1):

Hi please do it like below

**Way One**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

List<WebElement> mySpanTags = driver.findElements(By.xpath("ur xpath"));
System.out.println("Count the number of total tags : " + mySpanTags.size());
    // print the value of the tags one by one 
    // or do whatever you want to do with a specific tag

for(int i=0;i<mySpanTags.size();i++){
System.out.println("Value in the tag is : " + mySpanTags.get(i).getText());
// either perform next operation inside this for loop
if(mySpanTags.get(i).getText().equals("Consumer Staples (XLP)")){
    // perform your operation here 
    mySpanTags.get(i).click(); // clicks on the span tag
        }
    }

    // or perform next operations on span tag here outside the for loop
    // in this case use index for a specific tag (e.g below)
    mySpanTags.get(3).click(); // clicks on the 4 th span tag

}
```

**Way Two**

find the tag directly  `//span[text()='Consumer Staples (XLP)']`